# How to use buildKit's Go client

Tags: docker, docker-build

I'm trying to prototype a simple image builder using [builtKit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit), Docker's new image builder. I'm not using the command line interface but instead using the [client](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/buildkit/client). There's not much documentation on how to use this thing besides the [examples](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/tree/master/examples).

I need to run a build from a `Dockerfile` but the example [build-using-dockerfile](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/examples/build-using-dockerfile/main.go) isn't very intuitive. Most importantly, when I run the example with `build-using-dockerfile -t 'test:latest' .` (`'.'` being the current directory which contains a simple `Dockerfile`) the program stalls on

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
```

And is stuck there. How can I do this build using a `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just followed [these](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#build-using-dockerfile-utility) steps to configure and build `build-using-dockerfile`, you also need to configure and install `buildkitd` daemon.

This is what I did and it worked.

- Clone the buildkit project `git clone https://github.com/moby/buildkit`
- Configure and install `buildkitd` and `buildctl` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#quick-start).
- Make sure you start `buildkitd` daemon in background. `buildkitd --debug --root /var/lib/buildkit &`
- Now configure and install `build-using-dockerfile` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#build-using-dockerfile-utility).
- Then I build my custom docker image, here is the output I got

```
$ build-using-dockerfile -t testimage:v1 .
DEBU[0020] session started
[+] Building 0.0s (0/2)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.0s
DEBU[0020] new ref for local: x5y2556yo6yml2dzxpe1x1w4f
DEBU[0020] new ref for local: onaapearn65fka47xr3hu8b8j
DEBU[0020] diffcopy took: 6.13713ms
DEBU[0020] diffcopy took: 10.434052ms
[+] Building 0.1s (1/2)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0s
[+] Building 0.7s (2/3)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2sn => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s, => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1sg => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     0.5s
DEBU[0021] fetch response received                       response.headers="map[Content-Length:[156] Content-Type:[applica[+] Building 1.0s (2/3) => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2sk => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0sy => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s
[+] Building 1.2s (2/3) => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0sn => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s, => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0sg => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     0.9s
DEBU[0021] fetch response received                       response.headers="map[Content-Length:[1412] Content-Type:[application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json] Date:[Sat, 22 Jun 2019 11:30:03 GMT] Docker-Content-Digest:[sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63] Docker-Distribution-Api-Version:[registry/2.0] Etag:[\"s[+] Building 1.3s (2/3) => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s1 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0sf => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.1s
DEBU[0021] do request                                    base="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx" digest="sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json request.headers="map[Accept:[application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, *]]" request.method=GET size=1412 url="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63"
DEBU[0021] fetch response received                       base="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx" digest="sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json response.headers="map[Content-Length:[1412] Content-Type:[application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json] Date:[Sat, 22 Jun 2019 11:30:03 GMT] Docker-Content-Digest:[sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63] Docker-Distribution-Api-Version:[registry/2.0] Etag:[\"sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63\"] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000]]" size=1412 status="200 OK" url="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63"
DEBU[0021] fetch                                         digest="sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd8[+] Building 1.5s (2/3)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2sa => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0sf => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1si => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0sd => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.2s
DEBU[0022] fetch response received                       base="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx" digest="sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json response.headers="map[Content-Length:[739] Content-Type:[application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json] Date:[Sat, 22 Jun 2019 11:30:03 GMT] Docker-Content-Digest:[sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932] Docker-Distribution-Api-Version:[registry/2.0] Etag:[\"sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932\"] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000]]" size=739 status="200 OK" url="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932"
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:bfba26ca350c153700592ebd7e4613f25a7a8779289e041eb[+] Building 1.8s (2/3)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2sa => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s1 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s= => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0sd => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.5s
DEBU[0022] fetch response received                       base="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx" digest="sha256:bfba26ca350c153700592ebd7e4613f25a7a8779289e041eb68a97623277de82" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json response.headers="map[Accept-Ranges:[bytes] Cache-Control:[public, max-age=14400] Cf-Cache-Status:[HIT] Cf-Ray:[4eade3578f77cee8-IAD] Content-Length:[7237] Content-Type:[application/octet-stream] Date:[Sat, 22 Jun 2019 11:30:04 GMT] Etag:[\"ef3e5e49b6bd7977fffb3b8cc3729f78\"] Expect-Ct:[max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"] Expires:[Sat, 22 Jun 2019 15:30:04 GMT] Last-Modified:[Tue, 04 Jun 2019 22:32:16 GMT] Server:[cloudflare] Set-Cookie:[__cfduid=da0b42294258d98a7563847f958db178e1561203004; expires=Sun, 21-Jun-20 11:30:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.production.cloudflare.docker.com; HttpOnly; Secure] Vary:[Accept-Encoding] X-Amz-Id-2:[i5ODtFhOarpZHIPlInFHKf2LOdaN43logCkjX0SNk87mY4+pPI36eQ3H0CnWy1lhG05m4NhDKnk=] X-Amz-Request-Id:[A84C182FF892E492] X-Amz-Version-Id:[L2RUincMo02vR2Dt1LK5B1oppj0kjvZ3]]" size=7237 status="200 OK" url="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:bfba26ca350c153700592ebd7e4613f25a7a8779289e041eb68a97623277de82"
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json size=1412
[+] Building 1.9s (3/6)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s8 => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0sb => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.6s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 73B                                                                                    0.0s
DEBU[0022] resolving
DEBU[0022] do request                                    request.headers="map[Accept:[application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, *] Authorization:[Bearer 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.eyJhY2Nlc3MiOlt7InR5cGUiOiJyZXBvc2l0b3J5IiwibmFtZSI6ImxpYnJhcnkvbmdpbngiLCJhY3Rpb25zIjpbInB1bGwiXX1dLCJhdWQiOiJyZWdpc3RyeS5kb2NrZXIuaW8iLCJleHAiOjE1NjEyMDMzMDMsImlhdCI6MTU2MTIwMzAwMywiaXNzIjoiYXV0aC5kb2NrZXIuaW8iLCJqdGkiOiJ6MnlHUk1CdG1RS0g1OXlnUmJXZiIsIm5iZiI6MTU2MTIwMjcwMywic3ViIjoiIn0.dsQw07ln9xAaYqr-qAVv2cgNTzUOKB0W6r8pq3Tc5UF7bl0pEsCIIST-MXpNhVzNuz37Y1RbYh_aa4cKP4Rbxxm00ETOF3sDqxRuodSMIp16L3T2ICjKuftvZCWuDIllgWWJMYeVngoD3tRGx59jUNbs8N02WZ5x-l6DIKpYMfh0IEGZFspePai0a3NjLKlkNqNNnIIO24Pbi1U5F0VAZqRmfkcYyLVFIzji-LEuTI_s8wBRSnAKaXg38WhFicO4td_yVKX4WM2oHDgCPkrzWO-Hf6sDXebMu_agaYKy_ZdARSREU98uO8JN_hJSR3wCRw_8gJTtDrWN0TKd9Noz6w] User-Agent:[containerd/1.2.0+unknown]]" request.method=HEAD url="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63"
DEBU[0022] saved mq410rblsg97q4en3n0rv5mrw as local.sharedKey:context:context:
DEBU[0022] fetch response received                       response.headers="map[Content-Length:[1412] Content-Type:[application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json] Date:[Sat, 22 Jun 2019 11:30:04 GMT] Docker-Content-Digest:[sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63] Docker-Distribution-Api-Version:[registry/2.0] Etag:[\"sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63\"] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000]]"status="200 OK" url="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63"
DEBU[0022] resolved                                      desc.digest="sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63"
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json size=1412
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json size=739
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:f0e40e45c95e8b730fc083cbfbae0043a261ca769814d32092e89d4d5f959a28" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip size=5684641
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:bfba26ca350c153700592ebd7e4613f25a7a8779289e041eb68a97623277de82" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json size=7237
DEBU[0022] fetch                                         digest="sha256:e7c96db7181be991f19a9fb6975cdbbd73c65f4a2681348e63a141a2192a5f10" mediatype=application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip size=2757034
[+] Building 2.0s (4/6) => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s. => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s8 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s8 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.6sa => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.1s. => => resolve docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.0s5 => [internal] load build context                                                                                   0.0s1 => => transferring context: 73B                                                                                    0.0s
DEBU[0022] fetch response received                       base="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx" digest="sha[+] Building 2.2s (4/6) => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s[ => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0sM => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s/ => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0s: => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.6s= => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.3sy => => resolve docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.0sR => => sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63 1.41kB / 1.41kB                      0.0s4 => => sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932 739B / 739B                          0.0s
 => => sha256:f0e40e45c95e8b730fc083cbfbae0043a261ca769814d32092e89d4d5f959a28 1.68MB / 5.68MB                      0.2s
[+] Building 2.3s (4/6)
[+] Building 2.8s (4/6)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s
[+] Building 5.4s (4/6)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2sa[+] Building 6.7s (6/7)[+] Building 8.5s (6/7)[+] Building 8.5s (7/7) FINISHED => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.2s/ => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                                0.0s: => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.1s= => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                     0.0sA => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                     1.6sP => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  3.7s9 => => resolve docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4  0.0s
 => => sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2b4c63 1.41kB / 1.41kB                      0.0s
 => => sha256:881169baf03885268b54eb07c673bc27f394b263cb728dfd86ff2b65b3450932 739B / 739B                          0.0s
 => => sha256:f0e40e45c95e8b730fc083cbfbae0043a261ca769814d32092e89d4d5f959a28 5.68MB / 5.68MB                      0.3s
 => => sha256:bfba26ca350c153700592ebd7e4613f25a7a8779289e041eb68a97623277de82 7.24kB / 7.24kB                      0.0s6 => => sha256:e7c96db7181be991f19a9fb6975cdbbd73c65f4a2681348e63a141a2192a5f10 2.76MB / 2.76MB                      0.3s
 => => sha256:f0e40e45c95e8b730fc083cbfbae0043a261ca769814d32092e89d4d5f959a28 5.68MB / 5.68MB                      0.3s1 => => unpacking docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:b126fee6820be927b1e04ae36b3f51aa47d9b73bf6b1826ff19a59d22b2  3.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 73B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html                                                          1.1s
 => exporting to oci image format                                                                                   1.8s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                             0.9s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:9bb8e9d1941d16ab3ea13fed9b95dff4032ba07e865c6c2d155a8d00cbd9e5a8                   0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:9acf925d1b3ea1cc98c2053b1c450d993e1ff32dc3514cc90971c21458f25fce                     0.0s
 => => sending tarball                                                                                              0.9s
f1b5933fe4b5: Loading layer [>                                                  ]  32.77kB/2.757MB
DEBU[0029] remove snapshot                               key=paqys4xyo4hh9p90ck3u4duxm snapshotter=native
DEBU[0029] remove content                                key="sha256:9acf925d1b3ea1cc98c2053b1c450d993e1ff32dc3514cc90971c21458f25fce"
DEBU[0029] remove content                                key="sha256:9bb8e9d1941d16ab3ea13fed9b95dff4032ba07e865c6c2d155a8d00cbd9e5a8"
DEBU[0029] schedule snapshotter cleanup                  snapshotter=native
DEBU[0029] schedule content cleanup
DEBU[0029] removed content                               digest="sha256:9acf925d1b3ea1cc98c2053b1c450d993e1ff32dc3514cc90971c21458f25fce"
DEBU[0029] removed content                               digest="sha256:9bb8e9d1941d16ab3ea13fed9b95dff4032ba07e865c6c2d155a8d00cbd9e5a8"
DEBU[0029] content garbage collected                     d=5.429727ms
DEBU[0029] removed snapshot                              key=buildkit/11/paqys4xyo4hh9p90ck3u4duxm snapshotter=native
f1b5933fe4b5: Loading layer [==================================================>]  2.757MB/2.757MB
402522b96a27: Loading layer [==================================================>]  5.685MB/5.685MB
202e27ce64c9: Loading layer [==================================================>]     299B/299B
Loaded image: testimage:v1
INFO[0014] Loaded the image "testimage:v1" to Docker.
$
```

- The image was successfully created.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
testimage             v1                  9acf925d1b3e        13 seconds ago      20.5MB
$
```

In-short `build-using-dockerfile` uses `buildkitd` while building the image, which I guess was missing in your case.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you. Please also accept the answer if it helped. :)